# join_all with type ="full" gives wrong output

Tags: r, join

I create my list with:

```
datalist = lapply(file_list, function(x){read.csv(file=x,header=F,sep = "\t")})
```

Then use join_all:

```
joined <- join_all(dfs = datalist,by = "V1",type ="left" )  

> head(joined,5)
             V1     V2    V2    V2     V2
1 hsa-let-7a-3p    117   289   127     81
2 hsa-let-7a-5p 119867 84754 73053 101258
3 hsa-let-7b-3p    125   154    70     89
4 hsa-let-7b-5p  89748 61161 54270  47204
5 hsa-let-7c-3p     71    11    90      9

> joined <- join_all(dfs = datalist,by = "V1",type ="full" )

> head(joined,5)
             V1     V2
1 hsa-let-7a-3p    117
2 hsa-let-7a-5p 119867
3 hsa-let-7b-3p    125
4 hsa-let-7b-5p  89748
5 hsa-let-7c-3p     71
```

I want to use type="full" which will give NA for the samples which does not contain a specific rownames.

Example data:
df1:

```
hsa-let-7a-3p   118
hsa-let-7a-5p   60832
hsa-let-7b-3p   176
hsa-let-7b-5p   43252
hsa-let-7c-3p   188
hsa-let-7c-5p   21049
hsa-let-7d-3p   1509
hsa-let-7d-5p   509
hsa-let-7e-3p   57
hsa-let-7e-5p   2540
hsa-let-7f-1-3p 12
hsa-let-7f-5p   9940
```

df2:

```
hsa-let-7e-5p   233
hsa-let-7f-1-3p 113
hsa-let-7f-5p   99340
hsa-let-7g-5p   431
hsa-let-7i-3p   2914
hsa-let-7i-5p   703
hsa-miR-1-3p    15
hsa-miR-100-5p  3
hsa-miR-101-3p  110705
```

Comment: Which version of `plyr` library are you using? It works fine for me. You should restart your `rstudio`. Otherwise please provide reproducible example.

Comment: plyr_1.8.4. R version 3.3.3 (2017-03-06)
 Tried restart without success.

Comment: In that case you need to provide one or two dataframes. you may share only few rows.

Comment: Added two data frames as example.

Comment: What column names do you want to provide these two data.frames?

Comment: They should have the names as the file names. in this case df1, df2.

Comment: I have added my answer. `type = "full"` leads to work list `rbind` when all column names are same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason has been identified. The `join_all` works as merge(`rbind`) since all dataframes have same column names as `V1` and `V2`.

I changed the column names as `V1` and `V2` for `df1` and `V1` and `V3` for `df`. The `join_all` results looks as expected.

```
names(df1) <- c("V1", "V2")
names(df2) <- c("V1", "V3")

dfs <- list(df1, df2)

join_all(dfs, by="V1", type = "full")

#                V1    V2     V3
# 1    hsa-let-7a-3p   118     NA
# 2    hsa-let-7a-5p 60832     NA
# 3    hsa-let-7b-3p   176     NA
# 4    hsa-let-7b-5p 43252     NA
# 5    hsa-let-7c-3p   188     NA
# 6    hsa-let-7c-5p 21049     NA
# 7    hsa-let-7d-3p  1509     NA
# 8    hsa-let-7d-5p   509     NA
# 9    hsa-let-7e-3p    57     NA
# 10   hsa-let-7e-5p  2540    233
# 11 hsa-let-7f-1-3p    12    113
# 12   hsa-let-7f-5p  9940  99340
# 13   hsa-let-7g-5p    NA    431
# 14   hsa-let-7i-3p    NA   2914
# 15   hsa-let-7i-5p    NA    703
# 16    hsa-miR-1-3p    NA     15
# 17  hsa-miR-100-5p    NA      3
# 18  hsa-miR-101-3p    NA 110705
```

Comment: My input files does not have header. I have > 500 files, how do I add unique colnames to the files? datalist = lapply(file_list, function(x){read.csv(file=x,header=F,sep = "\t")})

Comment: @user2300940 Okay. You can think of changing the `function` used with `lapply`. One option could be let the 1st column be `V1` but change the 2nd column as name of `.csv` file itself.